# Take out first elements from nested lists in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

**Problem:** I need to transform this list: `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` to `[1,3,5]`, by taking only first items from each sub-list in first list and creating new list with all of them. Language is *SWI-Prolog*.

**My solution**: To do this, I wrote this code:

```
getFirstItems([], Result).
getFirstItems([H|T], Result) :-
    [H2|T2] = H, 
    append(Result,H2,Result2),
    getFirstItems(T, Result2).
```

**Issue**: But this fails to infinite recursion when tail always equals to `[[5,6]]`

**Question**: how to solve this issue and solve this problem correctly?

Comment: Define `head([H|_], H).` then `maplist(head, ListOfLists, Heads).` does it.

Comment: `?- getFirstItems([], [a,b,c]).` succeeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are complicating things too much. You need to reason with a declarative mindset, and thus implement **what the relationships between the list of lists and the list of first elements are**.

Here is a solution:

```
first_items([], []).
first_items([[H|_]|T], [H|T2]) :-
    first_items(T, T2).
```

Indeed, the only two things we need to state to describe that relationship are:

- If the list of lists is empty, then so is the list of first elements.
- a first element `H` is in the list of first elements, followed by the first elements (`T2`) of the rest of the list of lists (`T`).

Example queries:

```
?- first_items([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], Z).
Z = [1, 3, 5].

?- first_items(L, [1,3,4]).
L = [[1|_22058], [3|_22070], [4|_22082]].

?- first_items(L, Z).
L = Z, Z = [] ;
L = [[_22048|_22050]],
Z = [_22048] ;
L = [[_22048|_22050], [_22066|_22068]],
Z = [_22048, _22066]
…
```